# 90s/2000s anime/cartoon with a boy, a girl, and a robot looking for seven gems to prevent the planet from blowing up

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

So there was this one anime/cartoon when I was a kid that I watched but I can't remember its name.

But I remember that there were a boy, a girl, and a guy robot if you could say. The mission was to drive around with the tank and collect some kind of gems/diamonds (they are all different colour) and when they collect all 7 (I think it was that much) they will save the planet from blowing up.

Comment: When were you a kid (i.e., about how old would this be)?

Comment: Also, please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: @Micah That was about good 10-11 years ago,but the art looked like from the 90' or early 00'

Answer (score 3):

[Hamos The Green Chariot](https://myanimelist.net/anime/9106/Nogsaegjeoncha_Hamos) (Nogsaegjeoncha Hamos (original title) )

Originally aired: Dec 12, 1997 to Jun 12, 1998

> The Planet Terra, once called a morning star in galactic system, was
>   so beautiful. However, Terra is now under crisis that it may disappear
>   with big explosion in universe due to the pollution and warfare. Dr.
>   Chaco is the only one who knows the key of saving the planet Terra.
>   The only way to save Terra is to make rainbow system work with seven
>   mysterious crystals. To find 7 crystals, Dr. Chaco holds a race to
>   achieve his plot to build his own universal dynasty with the power of
>   the crystals. Riding Hamos, Rick joins the race not knowing Dr.
>   Chaco's plot. Rick comes to know the secret of the crystals on the
>   way of the race, tries to revive the planet Terra. This causes a war
>   between Dr. Chaco and Rick to get the 7 crystals and rainbow system.

You can watch the whole series [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjPaiDW5_kQ&list=PL9-0Qyl38oQ5OKW09ihEGwaSghn04H2Zv). (Warning, Serbian dub)

Opening here:

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you are talking about [Power Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Stone_(TV_series)).

It's an anime from the 90s/2000s, there are seven diamond-shaped colored stones, there is a boy, a girl and the MC transforms into something that resembles a robot. Not sure about the planet blowing up though.

Opening:

Answer (score 0):

Probably not it, but this sounds a bit like Dragonball GT-
Young boy (Goku)
Girl (Pan)
Robot (Giyru)
Seven gems to collect (Black star Dragonballs)
Aaand threat of the earth exploding.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This sounds promising; did they drive around in a tank?